# I have 3 bat file 1st.bat,2nd.bat,3rd.bat ..and I need to execute all 6 .bat file in a single bat file

Tags: windows, batch-file

I have 5 individual .bat file need to execute through a single file and my .bat files are placed on  location (ex D:\ESOFTWARE\PRODBatch) .

=>if 1st.bat exit with Zero then only 2nd.bat should execute like this it needs to continue till end
=>And need individual log (ex-1st_log.txt,2nd_log.txt...) file on the same location with appending on the old one.

Thanks for your help on this

Comment: You haven't asked for help with a defined programming code problem, so we cannot help you to fix it. If your expectation is that you can post a task, include some parameters and sit back whilst somebody codes it for you, you have not understood how this site works. Please take the [tour], then read through the links contained within [ask], to better understand.

Comment: What have you tried, and how has what you've tried failed? Ideally, you should provide a [MCVE] of what you've tried, and include specific information on how it failed, with error messages and/or erroneous output. [SO] is not a code-writing service; the best questions are those which provide useful information so that those who answer can guide you to devising your own correct answer. See [Ask] a Good Question (and [How do I ask and answer homework questions](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/334822), if relevant).

Answer (score 0):

If you are going to start everyone with set /p, it is not possible

```
Call batch1.bat && Call batch2.bat
Call batch3.bat && Call batch4.bat
Call batch5.bat && Call batch6.bat
```

Comment: Hi, Thanks for your update. But can you please narrate me in derails

Comment: Thanks for your update. But can you help me with details. Also batch2.bat should execute once Batch1.bat ended with Exit 0 and also I each batch log file need to be created .

Comment: I edited the message, but I don't understand, do you want batch 1 to finish, and start batch 2 right away?

Comment: `CALL` it can "`call`" an application with arguments, or it can give GOTO to others, with arguments too, if you want to know more, use `CALL /?`